# Get row data when checkbox in kogrid clicked

Tags: javascript, .net, json, knockout.js

I have kogrid with one column having checkboxes. I have 2 issues:

1. When I check/uncheck a checkbox I need to pull in the row values. How to get row data?
2. I have a save button outside kogrid. If I click save, the row values should be posted as json object.

HTML:

```
<div id="reconciliationGrid" data-bind="koGrid: reconciliationGridOptions"></div>
```

JS:

```
this.currentRowValues = ko.observableArray(); 
self.reconciliationGridOptions = { 
                      data: self.reconciliationGrid, 
                      canSelectRows: true, 
                      afterSelectionChange: function () { return true; }, 
                      selecteditems: this.currentRowValues 
                };
```

Comment: Show the code of the viewmode and html

Comment: <div id="reconciliationGrid" data-bind="koGrid: reconciliationGridOptions"></div>
javascript :
this.currentRowValues = ko.observableArray();
self.reconciliationGridOptions = {
            data: self.reconciliationGrid,          
            canSelectRows: true,
            afterSelectionChange: function () { return true; },
            selecteditems: this.currentRowValues
        };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the error in your code is here `selecteditems` but the correct is `selectedItems`,  see the snippet with an example that log the current selected row, show all selected in a div and on click in save button show alert with all selected data.

```js
function viewModel(){
  this.currentRowValues = ko.observableArray([]); 
   this.gridData = ko.observableArray([{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                                      {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                                      {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                                      {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                                      {name: "Enos", age: 34}]);
  
  this.reconciliationGridOptions = { 
                      data: this.gridData, 
                      selectedItems: this.currentRowValues ,
                      afterSelectionChange: function (selectedRow) { 
                        console.log(selectedRow);
                        return true;
                      }, 
                };  
};
viewModel.prototype.save = function(){
   alert(ko.toJSON(this.currentRowValues()));
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px;
 
}

button{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.selectedItems{
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.lukej.me/kogrid/2.0.6/KoGrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.lukej.me/kogrid/2.0.6/koGrid.debug.js"></script>



<div class="gridStyle" id="reconciliationGrid" data-bind="koGrid: reconciliationGridOptions"></div> 

<button data-bind="click: save">Save Example</button>
<br/>
<div class="selectedItems" data-bind="foreach: currentRowValues">
       <span data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. I will make required changes to my code and see if i resolve my issue

Comment: It's nothing @deepthi  , don't forget to mark as correct answer and upvote.

Comment: Hey Joel , my checkbox column is custom column not the built in checkbox column which comes with grid. I have a grid with one custom checkbox column because we want boolean values in database if checked true and unchecked false and also my grid has view button on each row. If i click on view button  all the details of the row should be displayed on a popup. what is the correct approach